# Call Overloaded methods with ternary operator?

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, ternary-operator, overloading

What is the rule that I can not call overloaded methods with checking `instanceOf` with ternary operator?

It may be a stupid question, but I want little explanation about this rule. You can see in screenshot, I can not refer to multiple methods by using the ternary operator.

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object object = new String("");
        Foo.load(object instanceof Integer ? (Integer) object :
                object instanceof String ? (String) object : null);
    }

    public static class Foo {
        public static void load(String s) {
            //
        }

        public static void load(Integer s) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

[image: sc]

Comment: the image is not accessible

Comment: @TheScientificMethod I re-attached Image, is it okay now?

Comment: I think it's more a case of that each returned value from a ternary operator must have the same type. As the value after the `?` is of type `Integer`, the value after the `:` must also be an `Integer` and you are providing a `String`.

Comment: This code doesn't produce compilation error for me. It will simply result in calling the `load(Object)` method.

Comment: @dave yes it may be, is it possible to do so anyhow?

Comment: @Eran let me know the editor, I will switch to that editor too :), I am using Android Studio.

Comment: @Khemraj I'm using Eclipse, but the Java version is more relevant. I'm using Java 8

Comment: you sure can refer to multiple methods in a ternary expression; but you can not have a ternary expression with different *result* type

Comment: @Eran I am using Java8 too. Strange that this program run in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method resolution is done in **compile** time. At the end of the day, you pass some expression that returns a value to a method. The compiler inspects the expression's type and determines which method it should call.

Here, you're attempting to write an expression that may return different types according to **runtime** information and invoke a method accordingly. And as you've seen, this just won't fly. Instead, you could explicitly invoke the different methods according to the type (the fact that they have the same name is inconsequential - they are still different methods!):

```
if (object instanceof Integer) {
    Foo.load((Integer) object); // Calls Foo.load(Integer)
} else if (object instanceof String) {
    Foo.load((String) object); // Calls Foo.load(String)
} else {
    Foor.load(object); // Calls Foo.load(Object)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object obj = getObject();

if(obj instanceof Integer)
    load((Integer)obj);
else if(obj instanceof String)
    load((String)obj);
else
    load(obj);
```

Error, because the overloaded method is been choosen at the **compilation time**, but **not runtime**, when you use `instanceof`. To move this check to the runtime, do use e.g. `if...else`.

**HINT**

```
load(obj instanceof String ? (String)obj : obj);
```

This is OK and does not throw compilation error, but what do you think, which overloaded method will be called, when `obj = "some string"`, `load(String s)` ???

**NO!!!** `load(Object s)` for both `String` and `Object` instance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But what if I don't need object type method.

Comment: Then you have `complie time error` when you use `instanceof`

Comment: Actually yes, `isntanceof` is not for choose overloading method.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, an empty string or null doesnot test for reference equality.

Your solution will work if the `Object object = new String("test");`
is there.

Also, for primitive types like int, float etc you don't really need instanceof.. instanceof is more for classes.

Here is a link on how instanceof really works:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it is same for new String("test")? I think compiler does not make difference between `""` and `"test"`